# NavigateToPage hangs in ASP.NET application

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm writing a web scraper using ScrapySharp that needs to use a simulated browser to log in and access data. The method, with the NavigateToPage call, works in a console application but not in my ASP.Net application. No NavigateToPage calls go through, including attempted navigations to Google, with or without https, with or without the default cookies parser.

```
 public static ScrapingBrowser GetESEBrowser()
        {
            ScrapingBrowser browser = new ScrapingBrowser();
            browser.UseDefaultCookiesParser = false;
            WebPage ESE = browser.NavigateToPage(new Uri("http://www.ese-co.com/storefrontCommerce/login.do"));

            PageWebForm login_form = ESE.FindForm("loginForm");
            login_form["usr_name"] = "blahblah";
            login_form["usr_password"] = "blahblah";

            login_form.Submit();

            return browser;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a deadlock in HttpRequest.GetResponseAsync, called in ScrapingBrowser.cs:272.
It seems to be related to the problem as described here:
https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html

Try an async Task like this to replace your GetESEBrowser():

```
public static async Task<ScrapingBrowser> GetESEBrowser()
        {
            ScrapingBrowser browser = new ScrapingBrowser();
            WebPage ESE = await browser.NavigateToPageAsync(new Uri("https://www.test.com"));

            //...

            return browser;
        }
```

You can call the Task with

```
GetESEBrowser().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Comment: This works for NavigateToPage, but Submit still hangs (it calls NavigateToPage).